# How to define the covariance for a finite set of vectors in an inner product space space V? What object is it?

Tags: probability, covariance, covariance-matrix, vector-fields

**Motivation:**

This question is motivated by a type of problems in medical imaging and computer vision as follows: suppose we've a set $A$ of points ("shapes") $\{x_1, ...x_d\} $in a Riemannian manifold $M$ ("shape space"). We'd like to have a notion of variance-covariance of the these points in $M$. So normally we first compute the Kärcher mean (assuming it exists and is unique) of $A$ by finding the point $\mu \in M$ so that it minimizes the sum of squared distances from all the points in $A$. Assuming all the points in $A$ lying in the cut locus of $\mu$, we lift all of them by inverse exponential map to $T_{\mu}M$, and call the lifts $\{v_1, ...v_d\}$ respectively.

**Main question:**

Let $\{v_1, ...v_d\}$ be a finite set $S$ of vectors in an inner product space $(V,g)$, where $g$ is the inner product on $V$. If $V=\mathbb{R}^n$ with canonical inner product, then covariance of $S$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, the standard variance-covariance matrix. **How do you define the covariance in our case? Is it a matrix? OR, is it linear map $Cov: V\to V$ ?** Note that, as someone asked in the comment section, that a matrix and a linear map aren't equivalent unless and until you fix the basis. So matrix alone doesn't define a linear operator and vice versa.

**ONLY if necessary**, (but I don't see why, see comments below), we can think of $v_i=X(\omega_i)$, where $X:\Omega \to V$ is a random variable whose values are in the inner product space $V$, and the sample space $\Omega$ has the probability measure $P$. Here $\forall i, \omega_i$ is a random event lying in $\Omega$.

I was thinking along this line: let $\bar{v}$ be the arithmetic mean for $V$. Now, we can consider the matrix whose $(i,j)$-th entry is 
$g(v_i-\bar{v}, v_j-\bar{v})$. Hence in my proposed definition, covariance of $S$ is a matrix with entries coming from the inner product of $V$. Is this right?

Comment: It makes no sense talking about covariance, variance or expected value for that matter without introducing first a probability measure. It may even be the uniform distribution over $V$, since it is finite and is compatible with the arithmetic mean you proposed, but you need at least one probability measure.

Comment: @MarceloVentura what probability measure do you use to define the mean and variance of a finite set  $A$ of numbers/vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$? Don't we just use the vector space of structure  $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ to define mean and variance of $A$? 

I agree that for a $V-$valued random variable, we do need a probability measure to define mean etc, and in that case I'm clear: covariance is a linear map :$V\to V$, whose representation w.r.t. the basis $\{ v_1, ...v_n \}$ is the matrix C with $C_{ij}:=cov(X_i,X_j)$, where $X=X_1.v_1+...X_n.v_n, X_j:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}, \Omega$ is sample space.

Comment: @MarceloVentura Just to be clear: in the definitions of covariance above, we're of course using the probability measure: we define $E(X):=\sum_{i=1}^{n} E(X_i) v_i$, where $\{v_1, ...v_n\}$ is an ordered basis for $V$, and $X:=\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i. v_i$. Note that E(X) is well-defined irrespective of the  basis chosen. Hence we can define $cov(X_i, X_j)$ as the integral $\int_{\Omega} (X_i-E(X_i)) (X_j-E(X_j))dP$, where $P$ the probability measure on (a Borel sigma algebra of) $\Omega$. Careful: we do NOT need probability measure on $V$ to define $E(X)$, as you said! Hope that explains things.

Comment: @MarceloVentura Speaking about the very first line of your comment, I believe we don't need any probability measure to define a function of the sample/statistic (sample mean, sample covariance...) chosen from a known/unknown distribution as we're only using finite, hence (any!) measure zero set of the sample space $\Omega$. BUT, to define the parameters of that distribution, we do need a probability measure on the sample space since we're using the full sample space, i.e. the domain of the random variable $X:\Omega\to V$. But we don't need measure on the codomain/target, $V$ in our case.

Comment: Because an $n\times n$ matrix represents a linear map from $V$ to itself, your question appears to have no content.

Comment: @whuber I don't think you understand the question at all, and your comment is wrong. You can't define a linear operator on $V$ by a matrix unless you fix the basis of $V$. There's no canonical way. The real question is: how do we define covariance of $S$ in this case? What kind of object is it? Is it a linear operator on $V$? Or, is it a matrix to start with? Hope that helps.

Comment: If I don't understand the question, please take that as evidence that it needs clarification.  If you believe the contents of your comments might make the question understandable, then please include relevant parts of them within the question itself.

Comment: If you form set of a Lebesgue measure zero not to understand it, there won't be any such evidence. So far, that's the case.

Comment: I will take that as an indication you have no intention of helping your readers understand your question, and so I will close it.

Comment: @Mathmath https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Win_Friends_and_Influence_People

Comment: @MarkL.Stone I read it. But I apply this to influence people I need to, that doesn't include someone here with not enough linear algebra background to understand the non-equivalence between a matrix and a linear operator on an abstract vector space. And I'm not searching for online friends, real-life is enough :)

Comment: In addition, please consult our [Help Center](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help), especially the following section : [Be nice](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: @chl I did. Now let me ask your fellow moderator (whuber) "If you don't have time to say something politely, just leave it for someone who does". Why? He, without understanding even a bit of the question, tells me "Because an $n\times n$ matrix defines a linear map from $V\to V$, your question appears to have no content." First off, his (whuber) math is wrong, and then he uses that to tell me my questions doesn't have a content??? I forgive his lack in linear algebra, but there's no need to be rude saying my question has no content!! Or since he's a moderator, he's forgiven? You decide!!!

Comment: Please do not misquote: my comment is there for all to see. Your *original* question (which is available in the edit record) referred to a "finite set of [$n$] vectors" in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and my comment used the word *represents*, not "defines." I am sorry that you have misread what I wrote and apologize that you misunderstood it as being impolite. It was intended, and remains intended, as an indication that your question needs some kind of clarification or amplification to be understood. Your subsequent *ad hominem* reactions are unconstructive and have only hurt your prospects of an answer.

Comment: I apologize of my subsequent reactions were rude, but even it they were, that's because your saying "no sense" to my question. And I did change $n$ to $d$. 

Now, speaking about math, again I've to correct you. Yes I know you said "represents", not "defines". Now please tell me, if there's no basis, what linear map on abstract finite dimensional vector space $V$ will a matrix represent? It's the equivalent question of "defines". If you fix a basis on $V$, a linear operator on $V$ and a matrix are equivalent. If not, then a linear operator isn't represented by a matrix and vice versa.

Comment: As a moderator, please be polite and say "could you explain this..." rather than "your question doesn't make any sense". I know I'm the scapegoat here, because you're the moderator and I'm not, but that doesn't mean you should get away with anything.

Comment: This will be my last comment in this thread. Please get the facts right. I never wrote that your question "makes no sense": that comment was posted by another user. Nobody is scapegoating you for anything--that does not and will not happen on this site. In fact, because you have attacked a moderator you have gotten away with behavior that simply would not have been tolerated if it were addressed to any other user: mods expect abuse as part of our jobs. But enough is enough: follow @chl's advice.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this link](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmc/section5/pmc541.htm), it's a slight difference: use the mean of each vector's elements instead of the overall mean.

Let $\boldsymbol{v}_1, \dots, \boldsymbol{v}_n$ be our set of length-$p$ vectors, where the $j$th element of $\boldsymbol{v}_i$ is $v_{ij}$ and the mean of the elements of the vector is $\bar{v}_i = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^p v_{ij}$ . With a slight abuse of notation, let $\boldsymbol{v}_i - \bar{v}_i$ represent the vector with the $j$th element as $v_{ij} - \bar{v}_i$.

Then the $ij$-th entry of covariance matrix is $g(\boldsymbol{v}_i - \bar{v}_i, \boldsymbol{v}_j - \bar{v}_j)$.

Comment: Let me see if I understand you correctly. But if I do you and the link don't say the same thing. Let $1\leq i \leq n$ denote the $i$-th vector vector $v_i$/observation/sample, and $v_{ij}$ measure the $j-$ th feature of the $i-th$ sample (so, height, weight...). Now your $\bar{v_i}$ is the average of all features for $i-th$ sample. We shouldn't take this average because it doesn't give us anything meaningful, and units are different for different features. But this is not what the link says: it does sum over same features for all samples to get $\bar{x}=[4.10, 2.08, .604]$.

Comment: I believe they did exactly the same thing that's standard. The dimension of each vector/observation represents the number of features involved for each sample. They write matrix $X$ of dimension $n \times m$ in a way so that the $i$-th row denotes all the $m$ features of $i$-th sample, $1\le i \le n$, the (unbiased) covariance matrix is  the $m \times m$ matrix $\frac{1}{n-1}{X'X}$, prime denoting transpose. Note: their $m=3, n=5$ and hence $S$ is $3\times 3$.

So far we're clear on this part, this is well known. Question is: what happens if the samples are vectors from a vector space $V$?

Comment: I see. You are right, I made a mistake, I am averaging over different values of the sample. When yuo say the samples are vectors from a vector space, are you saying, for example, that the "height" is a vector instead of a scalar? i.e. That an individual variable for a sample is a vector?

I'm not familiar with the problem context. Could you give an example, please? From your updated question, I think you mean that the vector would be the point on the manifold, and that represents one "sample". Please let me know if I'm completely wrong, it is quite likely!

Comment: "height" is a vector of dimensional $n$ if there're $n$ samples. Normally, in statistical experiments, we collect $n$ samples, and measure each of them $m$ times for $m$ features. So, each feature (height, age...) form a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

The vectors are not the points on a Riemannian manifold. They correspond to points on a manifold via the exponential map. Vectors really lie on the tangent space $T_{\mu}M$ of the manifold $M$. But this is for motivation: to show why we care about defining covariance for elements in a vector space. The vector space is really the tangent space.

Comment: So, for motivation, the real goal is to define covariance for points lying in a manifold, but modulo the exponential map, we're converting the problem to defining covariance in the tangent space at the Kärcher mean to the manifold. I'm not going into unnecessary detail, but just to mention that when the points are on the manifold, we've clear idea what the samples are and what the sample dimension is ($n$) and what the features are and what the feature dimension is ($m$).

Comment: I see. Thank you for the explanation, and I completely agree with your clear explanation of what statistical experiments measure (and thanks for using much more precise notation). I have to admit I have no experience with differential geometry, so I'm sorry I can't help. But I hope you can find the answer to his question-- it seems quite interesting!

Comment: Thanks for your positive comment, appreciate it! However, I wasn't looking for a differential geometric answer, it was merely stated for the motivation behind even considering covariance of a subset of $V,$ a vector space with an inner product. You see, without inner product, it doesn't make sense, as you can't define norm. Hence an inner profuct space in question. 

BTW: You could just look at the second paragraph of the question (main question), if you wish to.